# Preventing return of private inner class instance

Tags: c++

I have been playing around with inner classes in `C++`, and I'm bit confused right now.

#### My Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class outer{
private: 
    class inner{
    private:
        int something;
    public:
        void print(){
            std::cout<< "i am inner"<<std::endl;
        }   
    };
public:
    inner returnInner(){
        inner i;
        return i;
    }  
};

int main(){
    outer o;
    //outer::inner i = o.returnInner(); (1)
    //auto i = o.returnInner();         (2)
    //i.print();                  
    o.returnInner().print();          //(3)
    return 0;
}
```

This is compiled on Linux with `clang++-3.5` and `-std=c++14`.

- In **(1)** I'm getting a compiler error as expected because `inner` is a private inner class of `outer`.
- However, in **(2)** when the `auto` keyword is used, compilation is successful and the program runs.
- Everything works for **(3)**, too.

#### My question:

Why is this so? Can I prevent returning an instance of private inner class from outer methods while retaining the ability to move and/or copy them within the outer class?

Shouldn't the compiler elicit an error in **(2)** and **(3)** like it does in **(1)**?

Comment: If `inner` should not be accessible from the outside, why is `returnInner` then specified `public`?

Comment: I think it is made to show this strange behavior.

Comment: @AndyG it has, but i'll reformat to make that more clear

Comment: @KunaPrime This is a fantastic first question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: You can prevent copying and moving outside the `outer` class, but you can not prevent e.g. binding to a reference when that does not involve creation of a copy.

Comment: Just wondering, why would one want to return a private inner class anyway?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> why is it so 
>   Shouldn't compiler return error in (2) and (3) as in (1)?

It is an interesting question.. and answer to this is even more interesting.

In the code you posted, `inner`is a *name* of a type.  It is the *name* which is declared to be `private`, not the *type* itself<sup>1</sup> — accessibility of *type* doesn't make sense in the context of C++; accessibilty applies to *name* only — be it *name* of type, *name* of function, *name* of data . So when you hear something like *"the type X is a public class"*, it almost always means *"the name X is declared to be public, and it refers to a type and the type is omnipresent, it exists everywhere"*.

Coming back to why using `auto` doesn't give error, well because when you use `auto`, you're accessing the *type* without using its name, which is why it doesn't give error.

> how can i prevent return of an instance of private inner class from outer methods,

There is no way.

---

<sup>1. `struct { int data; }` is a *type*, without a *name* to refer to, though note that is not a valid declaration, because it lacks *name*. Either you've to declare an object of *unnamed* type as in `struct { int data; } obj;` Or give it a name as `struct data_type { int data; };`</sup>

Comment: Ability to use something without referring to its name is nothing special. One can return a reference to a private member variable and then use it as one sees fit. Very few people are surprised by that (though some still are).

Comment: @Nawaz thank you for  you answer, this is very interesting property of c++ that i had no idea about, and also it seems to me that this complicates type safety/locality when building APIs,

Comment: @n.m. for me, surprising thing is not that one can use something without referring to it's name, for me in this case is inability to enforce compile time error where it would be intuitive (at least for me)

Comment: Why do you expect a compiler error here, and no compiler error when you say `return &private_member_variable;` ?

Comment: Interesting. By the way if I declare a 'typedef inner inner_public ;' in the public section then I can instantiate a variable of type 'outer::inner_public'

Comment: @marom, and even cheekier, use    `typedef decltype(i) inner_t;` to give a name to the type of the `auto` variable.

Comment: @n.m. i don't have expectations from return statement (or it to cause any problems), what i'm somewhat surprised is that "private" type can be used outside defining scope.

Comment: @marom and AaronMcDaid thank you for sharing those "tricks"

Comment: Why a private type outside its scope surprises you and a private variable outside its scope doesn't?

Comment: @n.m.: I guess it is because when programmers talk about variable, they also talk about memory where the variable is created. And it is implicitly understood that only the variable can be `public`, `protected` or `private`; the memory where the variable actually resides (or rather *represents*), is accessible to all, through other means, and it doesn't make sense to say memory is `private`. But in case of *type* and their *name(s)*, there is no/rare similar talk that explains them. Also, people know *less* about type, compared to *data*, even though *type* **is** data, for certain programs.

Comment: @n.m. this is how i see it: variable is coupling between data (memory, or "instance") and type (how it should be used/seen). So when you are returning `&private_member` pointer of _member type_ on some part of memory is returned(you are returning typed "handle" to memory not variable). So far everything is fine, but when receiving scope (some outer scope) is using _member type_  which is declared as private that was counter-intuitive as i have not realized that type can not be declared as private, only type name can. In other words only names/variables can have scope not memory or types.

Comment: *variable is coupling between data (memory, or "instance") and type*. This is not really the case. Not languages are statically typed. Even dynamically typed languages have variables, and some of them even have private variables. More accurately, a variable is a name for an object. In C++ variable type is known at compile time but this is irrelevant for this discussion. So we see that a name can be declared private, but an object cannot. The situation is completely parallel to that of member types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's what you want but you can delete the copy constructor like that:

```
inner(inner const&) = delete;
```

Comment: with that one looses ability to copy object anywhere, and i want to do that inside outer but not to return inner from outer's methods.

Comment: you can use another constructor to copy it :D

Comment: Alternatively, `inner`'s constructor could be made private and `outer` get a friend of `inner`...